# Parameters in for loop, missing first one?

Tags: c, for-loop

I don't understand the for loop here. Could someone explain it to me? Normally. This one is missing a first statement and the second one says something different.

```
/* strcmp: return <0 if s<t, 0 if s==t, >0 if s>t */
int strcmp(char *s, char *t)
{
    for ( ; *s == *t; s++, t++)
        if (*s == '\0')
            return 0;
    return *s - *t;
}
```

Comment: Note that that is pretty bad code, the final subtraction can overflow and break. Also the pointers should both be `const`.

Comment: 'strcmp'' is a known system function name.  It is very bad programming practice to write functions with the same name as the system functions. (and things will get lots worse if the related header file is #include'd by anything)  Suggest using a unique function name, perhaps 'myStrCmp()'

Comment: indentation (and using braces around code blocks, even one statement code blocks) makes the code much more human readable  Suggest indentation (always uses spaces, not tabs for indentation) of 4 spaces after an opening brace '{' and un-indent before a closing brace '}'

Comment: the function will exit, returning 0, if the 's' string is shorter than or equal to the 't' string.   This is not the proper action of a strcmp function.

Answer (score 5):

According to C standard `$6.8.5.3`. For the following statement:

```
 `for(clause_1;expression-2;expession-3) statement`
```

Both `clause-1` and `expression-3` can be omitted, and `expression-2` could be replaced by an non-zero constant.

### Compiler's action

To answer your question fundamentally, let's look into how compiler handle your code.

#### For the `for` loop stmt in your code

From a compiler's aspect, the loop will finally be transformed into instruction sequence end with condition backward jump instruction as bellow.

```
   ...
   INST1
   INST2
   COND_JMP LABEL2
LABEL1:
   INST3
   INST4
   INST5
   COND_JMP LABEL1

LABEL2:
   ...
```

`for`'s `clause-1` will be put before the  LABEL1, such as `INST1` and `INST2`, therefore it is OK to omit such code. Since developer could also put such operations before the `for` statement.

`expression 3` will be put into the loop body (instruction sequence between `LABEL1` and `COND_JMP LABEL1`),  therefore `epression 3` code could also be put into the loop body directly in c code, that is why `expression 3` could also be omitted.

`expression 2` will be the condition used by the `COND_JMP` instruction, therefore if omitted directly, that means compiler will not insert `COND_JMP` outside the loop body, this will make `for` statement meaningless, that is why `expression 2` could only be replaced by non-zero constant. When replace by non-zero constant that means always true in C, and then the loop will be an infinite loop.

#### for the comma of your `for` stmt `expression-3`

According to C standard `6.5.17`, For he comma expression as following.

```
  expression, expression-2, expression-3..., expression-last
```

Here the `expression` could be an normal expression, or an assignment expression.

For such comma expressions, compiler will generate code which will evaluate all these expressions, and return the type and value of last one as the comma exression's return type and value.

Answer (score 3):

The initialization statement is empty. This means "no initialization action".

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of `for` loop is

```
for ( expression1 ; expression2 ; expression3 ) statement
```

Both `expression1` and `expression3` can be omitted. You can also omit `expression2` to make it an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Any (for) loop has three statements.

1. Initialization
2. Condition
3. Increment

Any of the fields above may be left blank based on requirement

```
for ( ; *s == *t; s++, t++)
```

Here

1. Initialization : There is no initialization
2. Condition : *s == *t (Till characters of the two strings are equal)
3. Increment : s++, t++ Increment pointers of both strings.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the 'for' loop
the first parameter (an optional parameter) (still needs the ';' separator)
(in this case, the variables of interest, 's' and 't', are
already initialized and available via the passed in parameters to the function, so the initialization parameter is omitted)

The second parameter is a conditional statement
While that condition is 'true', the 'for' loop will continue
to be executed.
(in this case, while the character pointed to by 's' is the same as the character pointed to by 't')

The third parameter (an optional parameter) 
(in this case, consisting of two statements separated by a comma ',':
the two statements step the pointers 's' and 't' to
point to the next char in their respective character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The `for(exp1; exp2; exp3) /* Body */` statement is, more or less, shorthand for this:

```
exp1;
while (exp2) {
    /* Body */
    exp3;
}
```